# ed25519 problem with libsodium implementation S_a + S_b = (s_a+s_b)*G

Tags: cryptography, javascript, elliptic-curve, libsodium

I'm trying to make my own implementation of atomic swaps by following [this article](https://comit.network/blog/2020/10/06/monero-bitcoin/). I use a low level [node.js bindings for libsodium](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sodium-native) for this.

If I understand the protocol correctly, then Alice and Bob have private keys (s_a, s_b) and public keys: S_a = s_a*G*,  S_b = s_b*G*. Where G=5866666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666 (base point of the ed25519 elliptic curve)

Thus, the relation should be fulfilled: S_a + S_b = (s_a+s_b)*G. But I can't achieve this equality. This is my simple JavaScript code:

```
    const sodium = require('sodium-native')

    let s_a = Buffer.from("0400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", 'hex');
    let s_b = Buffer.from("0600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", 'hex');
    let S_a = Buffer.alloc(sodium.crypto_core_ed25519_BYTES);
    let S_b = Buffer.alloc(sodium.crypto_core_ed25519_BYTES);
    
    sodium.crypto_scalarmult_ed25519_base_noclamp(S_a, s_a); //S_a = s_a*G
    sodium.crypto_scalarmult_ed25519_base_noclamp(S_b, s_b); //S_b = s_b*G
    
    let sumPublic = Buffer.alloc(sodium.crypto_core_ed25519_BYTES);
    let sumPrivate = Buffer.alloc(sodium.crypto_core_ed25519_BYTES);
    let test = Buffer.alloc(sodium.crypto_core_ed25519_BYTES);

    sodium.crypto_core_ed25519_add(sumPublic, S_a, S_b); //sumPublic = S_a + S_b
    sodium.crypto_core_ed25519_add(sumPrivate, s_a, s_b); //sumPrivate = s_a + s_b

    sodium.crypto_scalarmult_ed25519_base_noclamp(test, sumPrivate); //test = sumPrivate*G = (s_a + s_b)*G

    console.log("sumPublic = " + sumPublic.toString('hex'))
    console.log("test = " + test.toString('hex'))
```

Console output:

```
sumPublic = 2c7be86ab07488ba43e8e03d85a67625cfbf98c8544de4c877241b7aaafc7fe3
test = dbd33860dbf1de64256a42dad3069befdc07094809a620130a41a85740863432
```

But "sumPublic" **must be same as** "test" !? Because *test = (s_a + s_b)G = s_aG + s_bG = S_a + S_b = sumPublic*

Where is my error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

> sodium.crypto_core_ed25519_add(sumPrivate, s_a, s_b); //sumPrivate = s_a + s_b

is wrong. `crypto_core_ed25519_add` adds *points*, not scalars. For adding scalars you should use `crypto_core_ed25519_scalar_add`.